# Performing LINQ operations on List<struct>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a struct like this

```
public struct MyStruct
{
     public string Name;
     //More fields and construtors
}
```

Now if I have `List<MyStruct>` is there a way to use the `Contains()` feature of list?

This does not compile:

`if(_myStructList.Contains(x => x.Name == "DAMN!")){//DO STUFF}`

Here is the error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'MyStruct' because it is not a delegate type
```

I guess then this is not gonna work with structs?!

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing bracket for the if?

Comment: That was just a typo in the question, actual code I have is syntax error free! Thanks for pointing out though

Comment: Contains expects an instance of `MyStruct` which will need overridden equality comparison to match. Using `Any` would be a better solution as per Rafal's answer.

Comment: To aid future searches, the error text reported in this question corresponds to error code **CS1660**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to Enumerable.Any that doesn't use Linq is [List.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx):

```
if (_myStructList.Exists(x => x.Name == "DAMN!")) ...
```

Answer (score 13):

Try the `Any()` method in LiNQ:

```
using System.Linq;

if(_myStructList.Any(x => x.Name == "DAMN!")) ...
```

`Contains()` is a declared method of `List<>` and it expects an object as a parameter and uses equals to compare the objects.